# Hint to PyCharm that variable is modified

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a situation where a method does essentially the following to emulate a blocking call for something that doesn't actually block:

```
result = [None]
self.waiting_list.append((additional_data, result))
self.wait_for_response()  # when this returns, result will have been set by a different thread
self.waiting_list.remove((additional_data, result))
return result[0]
```

`additional_data` specifies some information for the operation and there may be multiple of these overlapping - locking for the list etc removed for clarity.

My problem is that PyCharm code inspection flags anything that calls it with a warning that the method doesn't return anything. I believe this is because all it sees is that `result[0]` is set to `None` and then never modified before being returned.

Assuming my belief is correct, is there any way to hint to PyCharm that the value is modified elsewhere?

Comment: I don't think so but you can just turn that inspection off if you find it irksome.

Comment: I prefer to keep it on because it's otherwise quite useful for catching mistakes. I can't really suppress it neatly either because it has to be suppressed at every caller rather than just once at the callee. I guess I'll just have to ignore the warnings for now unless someone knows some magic.